# PHP - running executable binary file through shell and printing output

Tags: php

I have an executable binary which i needs to run and interactively read from it and write to it when it asks for input

I'm talking about something like interactive shell, but in a web browser, such that:

- As soon as the binary produces output, i would like to send it to the browser
- As soon the binary requests user input, i would like the user to write the input from the browser

Now I've already did the same thing with `proc_open()`, I've used pipes to communicate with the running process and it worked fine, but i have to pass all required inputs before i run the binary

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
<?php

$descriptors = [
    0 => ["pipe", "r"],  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => ["pipe", "w"],  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => ["pipe", "w"]  // stderr is a pipe to write to
];

$process = proc_open('g++ test.cpp -o test.o && ./test.o', $descriptors, $pipes, "/home/ixcoders/Desktop");

if (is_resource($process)) {
    $inputs = "4\n5";

    fwrite($pipes[0], $inputs); // Add inputs to pipe
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); // Print Output
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]); // Print Errors
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    echo "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $return_value . "\n";
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is going to be a journey for you and I wish you lots of good fortune...

Generally, you're going to need to have a persistent connection open to the browser. This is done typically though WebSockets, though beacons and even WebAssembly (pure sockets) has started to be used to facilitate this real time communication. Full disclosure this is a personal repo [php sock](https://github.com/RichardTMiles/PHP-Websockets) which has the bare minimum to open a websocket connection using PHP. I've also experimented with [WebSocketD](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) which is like a websocket Gui (aka the apache or Nginx for websockets).

Side note your database connections (should you need any in WS) should just be reset/closed with every request... like every time you use it, not just per user connection. This proves to be the best way in my experience with MySQL at least.